# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrolltop' of undefined - Zurb Foundation and Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, menu, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have an Application build using Jquery Mobile and Zurb Foundation CSS. I have a common Menu in the header in master page and cloned copy in other pages.  I have used responsive Menu using Foundation's Topbar.

```
<div data-role="header" id="header-master" >

<div class="row" >

    <div class="small-3 medium-2 large-2 columns >

    </div>

    <div class="small-6 medium-2 large-2 columns " >

    </div>

    <div class="small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns ">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-no-turbolink role="navigation" id="home-context-menu">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>
```

The cloned menu is ,

```
<div id="header-child">

 </div>
```

When I tap the menu, it expands and responds for click/tap action. Doing the same again gives an error stating Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrolltop' of undefined. The console shows error in **Foundation.min.js**

I am cloning the menu in

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-next", function ()

     {
         $("#header-master").clone().appendTo("#header-child");
    }
    return false;

 });
```

I also tried cloning the header in **pagebeforecreate** event.

Comment: i can't see any element with id `header-master`.

Comment: Added the header - header-master and cloned header. Thanks

Comment: you are missing close bracket `)` in last

Comment: and di you try `$("#header-master").clone(true).appendTo("#header-child");`

Comment: Tried using   $("#header-master").clone(true).appendTo("#header-child"); Did't work. Results the same. Missed copying the brackets. Edited.

Comment: are you sure `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-next", function ()` is fired? try to alert something here.

Comment: Yes. It is firing. I did alert and also checked by keeping break point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer finally. I need to initialize Foundation library in all the pages where it is being used.

```
 /*INITIALIZE FOUNDATION CSS LIBRARY*/
    $(document).foundation();
```